# ajaxStop inside a Click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which displays a confirmation div when a link is clicked. The first time I run it this works, when the ajax request is finished the deleteConfirmation div slides up. But when I try it a second time (without a refresh) the confirmation div slides up every time it's slid down, even when this click isn't triggered.

```
$("#deleteConfirm").click(function() {

    if(debug)
        console.log("deleting "+$("#deleteConfirmationCampaign").html());

    $("#mappingsRemove").html("Deleting Campaign and Mappings...");

    // remove each mapping underneath the campaign
    deleteCampaign(apiUrl, "mappings", account+"/"+campaignToDelete[1], "confirmDelete");   

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { 

        $("#mappingsRemove").html("Finished");

        // slide up the delete confirmation dialog
        $("#deleteConfirmation").slideUp();

    });

});
```

I have several requests that occur in my deleteCampaign function, am I using this incorrectly?

I think whats happening is the first time this triggers it sets a global listener for ajaxStop. And of course this triggers like all of the time, so it always tries to slideUp the confirmation div. Perhaps I need to stop the document listener to ajaxStop after it's slid up for the first time?

Any advice would help thank you!

Comment: How many ajax events occur in your page? Setting the ajaxStop handler will fire _every_ time an ajax request finishes, regardless of whether it's in your click event or not.

Comment: So it would be dynamic, the number of delete requests could be 2 it could be 20, i think that the best way to solve this, would just to do a refresh after the document is finished with its requests, kinda makes the ajax bit completely useless, but I'm not sure how else to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unbinded the document and the ajaxStop function after the initial round of requests are finished,

Please let me know if this is going to cause any issues:

```
// listen for the ajax requests to finish
        $(document).ajaxStop(function() { 

            // set the mappings remove to say finished
            $("#mappingsRemove").html("Finished");

            // slide up the delete confirmation dialog
            $("#deleteConfirmation").slideUp();

            // unbind the listener
            $(document).unbind('ajaxStop');

        });
```

Comment: This approach might bite you if you use it on several locations, because everytime you remove all the 'ajaxStop'-event listeners at once.  So if you have two functions bound to ajaxStop and all the ajax-requests return the one function that is called first will unbind the other event-listener as well. Thus, the second function will probably never be called.

Comment: I see what you mean, this could cause a problem, in this specific case I only use it once. But on other pages, I do have multiple functions, I will keep this in mind, thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You're right about what happens.  But i'm not sure that ajaxStop is the best event to listen to.  It fires when all requests have finished, right?

I think you would want react only on the requests that are related to your deleteCampain function.

You could use deferreds to execute a function when all the significant request have returned.

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax("/deleteCampain.php"),
    ajax2 = $.ajax("/deleteCampain2.php");

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).then(function(){ 
    $("#mappingsRemove").html("Finished");
    $("#deleteConfirmation").slideUp();
});
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when

Comment: Another thing that may be of concern is the number of mappings under a campaign is completely random, so I would have an unpredictable number of requests that I could give the "when" function

Comment: The return values of $.ajax should be "deferred"s. They are event emitters that can call functions when the original ajax-call returns.  You can attach your callback in the object you pass the ajax-function or you can attach them to the deferred.   the $.when function takes a number of deferreds, (attaches listeners for you), and calls the when-function only when all the listeners have returned. So, No, the ajax-calls don't have to by sync.  It's just syntactic sugar to avoid nesting to many callbacks.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I did realize that when I read the "when" doc

Answer (score 1):

You might set a global boolean so it only runs one time:

```
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
       if (!window.firstStop) {
           $("#mappingsRemove").html("Finished");
           // slide up the delete confirmation dialog
           $("#deleteConfirmation").slideUp();
           window.firstStop = true;
       }
  });
```

Comment: so as soon as i set the boolean back it will trigger again, so I think  this would only be ideal it needs to be run once, is there a way to stop the listening of $(document).ajaxStop?